# Ruby Using Proc to store variables and retrieve them in a different function

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm still really new to ruby, and Im trying to understand Procs but i think i'm misunderstanding how to use them correctly. I want to store an action inside the proc and retrieve the stored action later. Here's what i've done so far, which clearly is incorrect and not working.

I have the following method:

```
def assign_proc_vars(action)
   Proc.new { |action| puts action }
end
```

Then I have:

```
def call_action_one
  assign_proc_vars "action1"
end
```

And Also:

```
def call_action_two
   assign_proc_vars "action2"
end
```

Then In my code I do:

```
call_action_two
```

And finally, in a new method:

```
def handle_action
   action = assign_proc_vars
   curr_action = action.call
   if curr_action == "action2"

   elsif curr_action == "action1"

   end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand why you've written the code this way at all, but the most pressing bug is that `puts` returns `nil`. Surely you wanted to **return** the value, not print it to STDOUT? So, delete the word `puts` from your proc.

Comment: In other words, with the way you've currently written it, `curr_action` will always equal `nil`, not `"action1"` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a Proc is really two-fold:

1. To act as a closure, capturing the variables at the current Binding.
2. To enable you to pass a named function around as if it were a variable.

Whether or not a Proc is really optimal for your use case, your code won't run because:

1. [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns nil.
2. You're not actually passing your Proc or assigning it to an variable accessible within the scope of the calling method.

Without attempting to refactor for a use case that I don't understand, the following use of [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead of #puts should fix the immediate problems with your code when using Ruby 3.0.1:

```rb
def handle_action action_proc, action
   case action_proc.call(action)
   when 'action1'; p 'Performing action one.'
   when 'action2'; p 'Performing action two.'
   else p %Q(Undefined action: '#{action}')
   end
end

# exercise each branch in your case statement
prc = Proc.new { p _1 }
['action1', 'action2', 'foo bar'].map { handle_action prc, _1 }

#=> 
["Performing action one.",
 "Performing action two.",
 "Undefined action: 'foo bar'"]
```